# plotting ufloats that are implicitly defined as an array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is my little test.py:

```
  1 import numpy as np
  2 from uncertainties import ufloat
  3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  4 
  5 x1 = np.arange(11)
  6 x = [ufloat(x, 0.1) for x in x1]
  7 
  8 plt.plot(x.n, np.arange(11))
```

It produces the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n'`

I guess it's because I defined the ufloats as an array and now the values are with the errors itself elements of that array. But I can still calculate with `x` and get correct errors from the propagation of uncertainties.
How can I tell python to plot only the nominal values but being still able to calculate with the errors of the ufloats?

edit:
I tried:

```
  5 x1 = np.arange(11)
  6 err = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
  7 
  8 x = ufloat(x1, err)
```

It gives the following error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should extract each nominal value like this:

```
plt.plot([x[i].n for i in np.arange(11)], np.arange(11))
```